# Keep original input as part of print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, while-loop

I have two inputs, a and b, and I am trying to perform an operation. My code is as follows:

```
a = int(input("Enter an integer A to be multiplied: "))
b = int(input("Enter an integer B to be multiplied: "))

while b > 1:
    b //= 2
    a *= 2
    sequence = a, b
    print(sequence)
```

If I enter 34 and 19, this is the output

```
Enter an integer A to be multiplied: 34
Enter an integer B to be multiplied: 19
(68, 9)
(136, 4)
(272, 2)
(544, 1)
```

**However, I would like to include my original input 34 and 19 in the output.** What do I need to change/add in order to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the original values and then print them as tuples:

```
In [59]: a = int(input("Enter an integer A to be multiplied: "))
...: b = int(input("Enter an integer B to be multiplied: "))
...: orig_a = a
...: orig_b = b
...: while b > 1:
...:     b //= 2
...:     a *= 2
...:     sequence = a, b
...:     print((orig_a, orig_b),sequence)
#Output:
Enter an integer A to be multiplied: 6
Enter an integer B to be multiplied: 7
(6, 7) (12, 3)
(6, 7) (24, 1)
```

Or if you want all values in one tuple just change:

```
sequence = orig_a, orig_b,a, b
print(sequence)
#Output:
Enter an integer A to be multiplied: 34
Enter an integer B to be multiplied: 19
(34, 19, 68, 9)
(34, 19, 136, 4)
(34, 19, 272, 2)
(34, 19, 544, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would probably work, since when `b` falls below 2 the integer division will round down to zero:

```
a = int(input("Enter an integer A to be multiplied: "))
b = int(input("Enter an integer B to be multiplied: "))

while True:
    print(a, b)
    b //= 2
    a *= 2
    if b < 1:
        break
```